# They said they would contact me tomorrow but they didn't

Tags: human-resources, feedback

After the last stages of those interviews, they gave me feedback`

"Hey! Today our HR urgently took a day off, tomorrow I will contact you based on the results of those calls. Don't lose us :)"

what do you think about this?

Comment: That is, if they didn't write to me today, then it’s better to write to them tomorrow, right?... and moreover, at the end of the technical interview they told me that "there was a very positive result".

Comment: What day is "tomorrow" in this context?  How long have you waited?  What time zone is the company in, and what time zone are you in?

Comment: They said it yesterday, that is, tomorrow is today.... their time zone is -2 hours from my timezone

Comment: What time zone are you in?  For me, it is now 1:20pm, meaning 1 hour ago (when you asked this question) was roughly noon.  If you're in the same time zone as me, that means their time (in their time zone) is 10am.  Assuming they start work at 9am, you've given them a whole 1 hour to email you before getting nervous.  That sounds kinda ridiculous.

Comment: my timezone GMT+4

Answer (score 1):

There might be plenty of reasons for them not contacting you (PTO, sick-leave, some other emergency or they were to busy or simply forgot). I would give them a couple of days - if they didn't reply with their feedback, just contact them..

In your situation I wouldn't push too hard, I'd wait till Monday and then write them an e-mail. I usually tend to only get exited once I have a written contract in my hands, everything before that point is a lot of speculation which can lead to disappointment.

Feel happy and confident about the fact that they see you as a valuable and promising candidate and continue to apply to other positions until you have a written offer in your hands..

Comment: yes, I agree with you, I think there is a chance because they still wrote "don't lose us :) "

Comment: they still haven't responded today

Comment: @user138040 If you are really that exited about the job-oportunity and don't want to wait a couple of days, just e-mail them the tomorrow and request a follow-up regarding the interview process in a polite way and gentle way. Good luck and keep us updated if you like..

Comment: sent an offer today ))

Comment: @user138040 Great news - congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following things, and others, are possible:

1. Their "urgent" issue took longer than planned.
2. They had to catch up on work they missed yesterday.
3. They had additional urgent tasks or meetings today.
4. They just plain forgot to message you.

All of these are reasonable reasons why they wouldn't message you as scheduled.  Tomorrow (the day after "tomorrow" in the email), send them a reply saying something like "hey, I didn't hear from you yesterday, what's up?" and go from there.

Comment: Ok thanks, i just texted them, let's wait what they say

Comment: Almost fully agree wtith your answer, but don't you think _"hey, I didn't hear from you yesterday, what's up?"_ is a bit of a lax tone while being in an interview/hiring process?

Comment: 5. Another candidate was successful and they and are too busy/lazy to contact you

Comment: @iLuvLogix I'm a lax tone kind of person.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Sure, but that's not an acceptable reason for not following up.

Answer (score 0):

> They said they would contact me tomorrow but they didn't

They gave you a specific date when they would contact you and they did not.  At this point, if you are still interested in this company, you should call them to follow up.

Comment: Yes, I agree, then tomorrow I will write to them....  and moreover, at the end of the technical interview I was told that "there was a very positive result from them".... I hope there is a chance ?